# How one software runs another software

Tags: java, jvm

I am baffled with the statement/s which I have often read:

A Java program runs inside (or by) JVM. The doubt which I have is, how one Java program is run by another program i.e. by JVM.

How can one software read other software?

This might seem very trivial or no sense question, however the more I think about this, the more doubt I get "how one software can run other software".

Any help to understand this, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Software is just bytes in a file.  The JVM just opens up the file, reads the bytes, and depending on what the bytes say it does one thing, and if the bytes are something different it does something else different.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhEoCNEPdhY

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it opened the doors for new thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The doubt which I have is, how one Java program is run by another program i.e. by JVM.

The JVM is a program. It

- read the class file which contains the compiled Java class.
- it has an interpretor which performs the actions in the Java byte code.

The code can be compiled to native code which the JVM calls to speed up execution.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, indeed it opened doors of thinking.

Comment: @CuriousMind you could implement a JVM, in a JVM. ;)